# Unity - Mixing two render textures with proper depth information

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a base camera that renders some 3d backgrounds to a texture, with the clearing flag set to skybox and a depth of 0, then I have another camera with the exact same settings but the depth set to 100. This second camera is rendering the main character to another texture and is a child of the first one.

I have tried to set the depthbuffer of the first RT on the second camera by calling SetTargetBuffers but that just displays really funky results, like if the camera was on a different place and the backgrounds are not rendered.

If I don't call SetTargetBuffers and just assign a RT to each camera, it renders ok but then the characters on the second one always gets drawn on top (expected I guess since the second RT doesn't have any depth information of the 1st one).

I'm using the built-in pipeline. Any idea how could I render these 2 RT while sharing the same depth buffer?